# FIrebase Geofire + query (age betwen 20 to 30) + query (height 5 to 7 feet)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I have created 2 nodes in firebase database.

location

```
|
pushkey - g 
         |- lat - 45.55
         |- lag - 76.88
       - userid: 87a8dhia87hdkhk
```

user

```
|-USerid1

    |- age: 42
    |-height: 7 feet
    |-language: hindi

|-USerid2

    |- age: 22
    |-height: 5 feet
    |-language: franch
```

Now, I am getting nearby users using geofire and whatever keys I get I fetch data for those users and filter them locally. It is working ok for me for now but as number of users will increase, It can get worst.

I am hoping firebase functions can have some solution where I can pass filter criteria from app to functions and functions can return me a snapshot or List depends on my filter parameters. If that possible and if yes, can you help me with that?

Comment: how increased users will effect it? are you saying that increased number of users inside the radius of the user will affect the performance of the application?

Comment: yes, right now I am having 100 users in one area. so, I get 100 users data and go through each user to check if it fits my filter criteria. Imagine it with 10000 users in one area. It's too much work on the client side I feel. Plus, I don't want to show 10000 users. I might want to limit 30 results. and I have to do that on the client side.